# How does the compiler deal with the inputs following an invalid input exactly?

Tags: c++

I know that, roughly speaking, when the user enters an invalid input, 0 will be assigned to that input (the failbit flag is set on the input stream) and all the subsequent inputs becomes unreliable.

In such cases, I wonder if some unreliable value (or some value with special meaning like 0 above) will be **assigned** to those subsequent inputs? Or if those those subsequent inputs will simply be **escaped**?

---

I actually made a toy program with multiple `std::cin >> variables;` statements to see if any value would be assigned to variables after the failbit flag has been set.

[image]

It seems that, on my computer, all those subsequent `cin` are being escaped and the variables that would have been assigned a value by those subsequent `cin` remain to have the original values which were assigned to them during their initialisations (a is 0 while b and c are still 100 and 1000 respectively).

May I ask if such escapes happens all the time? Or if such behaviour differs from machine to machine?

---

Also, may I ask if the invalid input remain in the input buffer after the failbit flag is set unless we clear the input buffer?

Comment: It's not the compiler doing this. It's the code of the standard lib implementing that behaviour.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt): *If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set.* The behaviour may be different for different types tho.

Comment: I wondered myself whats the use of assigning 0 (introduced in C++11) when it already fails for something as innocent as `ss >> a >> b;` (well not really "fail" but results can be unexpected). I think there is a nice question lurking behind this text, but imho some code is needed to be more clear

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code. Code described as text is unecessarily difficult to understand. In particular it is not clear what exactly you mean with "all those subsequent cin are being escaped"

Comment: @StefanRiedel Thank you very much for pointing that out :) I've just edited

Comment: Escaping sequence is just for string literals to resolve grammar issues in source code. Input/output stream doesn't have any kind of escape sequence functionality!

Comment: You've wrote `I actually made a toy program` just show it, provide [mcve].

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you for your reference, may I ask in that case, how are the subsequent extractions being treated?

Comment: @MarekR well he didn't exactly say "escape sequence" so it's unclear what he meant by "escaping", but by context it seems he meant "skipping" or something like that.

Comment: this [compiler explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/vvcEnY45o) shows atleast, that it's skipping on subsequent extractions

Comment: streams do not escape or skip anything (except leading white characters) unless you will request to do something like this in code. Again provide [mcve] since your wording choice is misleading.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number and MarekR Thank you for reminding me about that, I've now added

Comment: @MarekR Hi, I think I mean "skipping" or "ignoring" more than "escaping", sorry about the wording

Comment: @StefanRiedel You should have written [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099703/how-does-the-compiler-deal-with-the-inputs-following-an-invalid-input-exactly#comment120362257_68099703) as answer. It's very illustrative and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, arithmetic & num)` are functions that an implementation (not just "the compiler") must provide. The standard defines what they do.

The steps are laid out in the definition of [*FormattedInputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) and [`std::num_get::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get). Specifically:

> If the sentry returned `false` or sentry's constructor threw an exception, no input takes place

> If the conversion function fails to convert the entire field, the value ​`0`​ is stored in `v`.

So the first input failure writes `0` to a number, and subsequent calls don't modify the right hand side argument.

Comment: The question was, what happens AFTER a failed extraction.